# iPhone UITableView image background when table is empty

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, background

I would like to show an image background when my UITableView is empty.
Currently I tried adding a UIImageView to my view controller that contains a table, but XCode doesn't allow it.

Is there a good way of doing it?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You could either add an image view on top of the table view or change the background view of the table view.

```
// Check if table view has any cells
int sections = [self.tableView numberOfSections];
BOOL hasRows = NO;
for (int i = 0; i < sections; i++) {
    BOOL sectionHasRows = ([self.tableView numberOfRowsInSection:i] > 0) ? YES : NO;
    if (sectionHasRows) {
        hasRows = YES;
        break;
    }
}

if (sections == 0 || hasRows == NO)
{
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"test.png"];
    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];

    // Add image view on top of table view
    [self.tableView addSubview:imageView];

    // Set the background view of the table view
    self.tableView.backgroundView = imageView;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, nice trick. By the way, how can I visually design a UIView and use it as a layer on the table? I have no longer have the option of simply designing a view with the new XCode storyboard...

Comment: You can design the view by creating a new nib file and load it into a UIView.

Comment: I used to do it on the old XCode. The new XCode that comes with storyboards seems to be working in a different way. It doesn't allow you just to create a new custom size view and all the views are on the same storyboard file.

Comment: If the first sections has rows and the second section doesn't then this will not work. as it will set the hasRows back to NO for the second section. You should just set hasRows to YES if there are rows and then break.

Comment: @Jonathan. That was an inadvartant mistake. I've corrected it now. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 4):

`UITableView` has a `backgroundView` property.  Set this property to the `UIImageView` containing your background image.

Comment: Please note, that I don't want to show any background for the UITableView. I want to shown some background only when the table has no cells to show. I simply want to hide the table and put a background instead. Will your suggestion work for that?

Answer (score 3):

In you **numberOfRowsInSection** method:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    if data.count > 0 {

        return data.count
    }
    else{

        let image = UIImage(named: "Nature")
        let noDataImage = UIImageView(image: image)
        noDataImage.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: tableView.bounds.width, height: tableView.frame.height)
        tableView.backgroundView = noDataImage
        tableView.separatorStyle = .none

        return 0
    }
}
```

**numberOfSections** should be greater than 0

Answer (score 0):

To be able to use constraint on the added background view using NSLayoutConstraint

declare the view programmatically, in my case a UILabel

```swift
var emptyListLabel: UILabel = {
   let label = UILabel()
   label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
   label.textColor = .black
   label.text = "No shipment with the selected filter!"
   label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 11)
   label.numberOfLines = 0
   return label
}()
```

then in your dataSource delegate function - `numberOfRowsInSection`, put this:

```swift
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if model.count > 0 {
            emptyListLabel.removeFromSuperview()
            return model.count
        }
        else{
            tableView.addSubview(emptyListLabel)
            NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
                emptyListLabel.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: tableView.centerXAnchor),
                emptyListLabel.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: tableView.centerYAnchor),
            ])
            tableView.backgroundView = emptyListLabel
            tableView.separatorStyle = .none
            return 0
        }
        
    }
```

it looks like this-
[image: image with centralized label when list is empty]